# Cannot convert enums to string in typescript 2

Tags: typescript

Before Typescript 2 version I used to convert enums to string in the following way:

```
public myFunction(myEnum: MyEnum): string {
   return MyEnum[myEnum];
}
```

Now with the new version of Typescript the following error is generated: An index expression argument must be of type 'string', 'number', 'symbol' or 'any'.

Do you have an idea how I could fix this?

Answer (score 1):

I believe the error you are getting is that you declare that `myFunction` returns a string, but it actually doesn't return anything...

```
public myFunction(myEnum: MyEnum): string {
   console.log(MyEnum[myEnum]);
}
```

Fix it by returning the value...

```
public myFunction(myEnum: MyEnum): string {
   return MyEnum[myEnum];
}
```

Or by changing the return type...

```
public myFunction(myEnum: MyEnum): void{
   console.log(MyEnum[myEnum]);
}
```

Full example to show things do still work.

```
enum Example {
    Red,
    Blue,
    Green
}

alert(Example[Example.Red]);

function myFunction(myEnum: Example): string {
   return(Example[myEnum]);
}

alert(myFunction(Example.Blue));
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It is my fault I published incorrect code. In fact this is not the problem. It is related to this announcement: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/typescript/2016/08/30/announcing-typescript-2-0-rc/, but I am not sure how to fix it. I have the same code, it compiles without errors with TypeScript 1.9 and has errors in later TypeScript